# Sculptie Maps for Second Life

Tags: mesh

I want to make a sculpt map for use in Second Life but all of the tutorials I am finding are for older versions of blender and I don't see the same options or tools in my version (2.77).

I understand that sculpties are an outdated tempory fix that Second Life came up with but I want to be able to animate the model with less land impact.

Comment: If I remember well... but effectively all this is a bit old... this is a bake process using normal to object as parameters for the bake. But there are constraints in the UV map shape (it must feel the texture, I think). I cannot test it as I cannot go back to SL these times (so I wont answer). But generally even if a sculpty is one prim, many meshes are lower cost than that (you can make relatively complex meshes of 0.5 prims if they are not too large).

Comment: I think the principles here are good : https://sites.google.com/site/amandalevitsky/sculptedprims. But for the nowadays version of Blender use "bake type = normal" and "space = object" (Cycles)